# Drawer Navigator position x

Tags: react-native, layout, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I'm using react-native-navigation and I want to track custom Drawer Navigator's position x, so I call onLayout event like this:

```
<View styles={style.container} onLayout={(event: Object) => {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.x);
}}>
  (...)
</View>
```

But onLayout is triggered only once, event if I move Drawer Navigator. Is there any other way to track its position?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?